# Стало беспомощно?

Tags: наречия, лексическая-сочетаемость

Фраза из «Кафки на пляже» Харуки Мураками:

> От этой мысли мне стало страшно беспомощно и одиноко.

Что не так с этим наречием? Или с этими, рядом идущими? Может быть дело в недостаточности глаголов-связок?

Answer (score 3):

В монографии "Переходные конструкции в синтаксисе" д-ра филологических наук В.В. Бабайцевой говорится следующее.

> Приведем примеры образования безлично-предикативных слов по модели: *В
>   окнах стало свинцово* ... ***Сначала было одиноко, беспомощно*** (И. Герасимов. И возвращаются ветры.) *Еще водно, рыбно и лесно на Руси*. (Л. Леонов. Русский лес.) *Семену Ивановичу стало робко*. (А. Н. Толстой. Ибикус.)

Я не чувствую резкого перехода между **было** и **стало**, поэтому считаю, что выражение "стало беспомощно" вполне допустимо, хотя и звучит непривычно в цитате из вопроса.

Ещё несколько цитат не самых распространённых вариантов употребления слова "беспомощно":

> Это было сказано страшно беспомощно. ("Радуга", 1963)
>   Личность
>   человека кажется ничтожной, жалкой, выглядит растерянно, страшно
>   беспомощно. ("Вопросы философии", 1948)
>   ...чуть не сказал Тенька, но
>   это было бы совсем беспомощно. ("Тополята", В. Крапивин)
>   На душе у него
>   было беспомощно и пусто. (С. и М. Дяченки)
>   На душе было особенно
>   беспомощно и тяжело. (Б. Любимов)

Comment: «Личность человека... выглядит растерянно, страшно беспомощно.» Здесь однако не наречие: личность выглядит беспомощной... Может быть и не надо было ему, этому слову, под другую часть речи мимикрировать? Ему же эта роль не по силам.

Comment: *Здесь однако не наречие: личность выглядит беспомощной...* Конечно, не наречие, если вы превратили его в прилагательное. А в исходном варианте - наречие.

Comment: Не поняли... Говорю именно о кратком определении или же слове категории состояния — у Мураками, т. е. у автора перевода, конечно. Подумалось, что нормально было бы перевернуть: мне стало одиноко и беспомощно страшно.

Comment: Но ведь изменится мысль автора, появится чувство страха, а у автора его нет, там состояние беспомощности и одиночества,  страшно - разговорное наречие степени = очень ( очень беспомощно), мне нравится это слово состояния, оно образное, в одном ряду с эпитетами.

Comment: Мы не говорим «мне стало беспросветно», оттого что у нас бывает состояние беспросветности.

Comment: @shampar Я чувствую себя беспомощным -> мне беспомощно. Но нельзя сказать, что кто-то чувствует себя беспросветным или т.п., поэтому  "мне  стало беспросветно" не годится, по-моему.

Comment: "Состояние беспросветности" тоже не годится, по-моему. Есть ощущение беспросветности (беспросветность характеризует ситуцию, а не человека).

Answer (score 1):

*От этой мысли мне стало страшно беспомощно и одиноко.*

Мне это предложение не кажется стилистически верным. Беспомощно – это обычное (обстоятельственное) наречие, например: выглядеть (как?) беспомощно.

Но это не предикативное наречие, которое можно использовать в безличном предложении, нельзя сказать: мне сейчас беспомощно. Или: мне стало беспомощно.

Возможно, раньше употреблялись обстоятельственные наречия в значении безличных предикативных, но сейчас такие конструкции кажутся устаревшими.

Вариант редактирования: **От этой мысли мне стало беспомощно одиноко.**

Здесь обстоятельственное наречие *беспомощно* относится к предикативному наречию *одиноко*.

Comment: Некоторые примеры употребления, которое Вы отвергаете, относятся ко второй половине 20-го века. *Но я через пять минут из зала ушел, потому что все-таки было робко. [Анатолий Эфрос. Профессия: режиссер (1975-1987)]*.

Comment: Ваш вариант редактирования искажает смысл (в оригинале никому не было страшно).

Comment: "Страшно" я для выразительности  и красоты слога добавила. Ну если никому не страшно, то пусть будет просто "беспомощно одиноко" или "страшно одиноко".   Зачем использовать лишние слова, идея беспомощного одиночества вполне выражена. А что касается грамматики, но ее нарушать не следует, у нас нет предикативного наречия "беспомощно", это даже на слух определяется. Или Вы думаете, что есть?

Comment: Толковый словарь Ефремовой: беспомощно — **II** _предик._ https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/141604/Беспомощно

Comment: «Предикативные наречия, омонимичные кратким прилагательным среднего рода, имеют степени сравнения»? А у "беспомощно" — нет, разве что степень предельной крайности. При этом усиление (страшно)  — крайность запредельная.

Comment: 1) Я вообще-то имела в виду предикативные БЕЗЛИЧНЫЕ наречия, которые могут описывать состояние человека в предложении "мне весело" (нельзя сказать "мне беспомощно"). 2)" Страшно"  в значении "очень" от страшный (Разг.) Выделяющийся среди других своими положительными или отрицательными качествами; исключительный. С. холод. С-ая скука. С-ая боль. С-ая суматоха. С-ая бедность.  Сочетание "страшно беспомощно" весьма сомнительно и по фонетике, и по смыслу, и по стилю. Скорее всего, это похоже на авторский вариант, причем не самый удачный (я так думаю).